# Getting [Errno 39] Directory not empty issue while installing python modules inside shared folder of vagrant using virtual environment

Tags: vagrant, virtualenv, virtualbox, python-3.7, virtualbox-guest-additions

I am trying to build debian package of my module inside shared folder of VM (Vagrant + VirtualBox) using virtual environment and I am gettting following error

```
[Errno 39] Directory not empty: '__pycache__'

<mymodule_path>/devenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/__pycache__
```

python version : 3.7 
vagrant version: 2.2.10 
Guest addition plugin: latest 
Virtual Box version: 6.1

Can you help me here to resolve this issue